# PyMC3: how to efficiently regress on many variables?

Tags: python, data, bigdata, bayesian, pymc3

I am sorry ahead of time if this seems like a basic question, but I had difficulty finding resources online addressing this. In PyMC3, when building a basic model of a few variables, it is easy to define each on their own, like `alpha=pm.Normal('alpha',mu=0,st=1)`, and manually add them all with each other. However, what are the standard approaches when one is dealing with dozens/hundreds of variables, each needing a prior?

I see that the `shape` argument is helpful in defining many priors at once, but after that how do you then add them all together in the mean equation (if your model specifies a Normal distribution), or what if different groups of variables need different priors?

I would heavily appreciate any advice on this matter, as I'm switching over to PyMC3 from regular machine learning and regression.